# Adding a column in Pandas while editing the values

Tags: python, pandas

Add a new column to the homework2 dataframe called ADJ_HDI that is the HDI value if the HDI value is greater than .5 else it is equal to zero.

We have been trying for hours to create the syntax for this with no luck, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, assuming your HDI is in a column called 'HDI' and you are trying to create a new column that is equal to the HDI, or 0 if HDI is < .5

```
def adj_hdi(row):
    hdi = row['HDI']
    if hdi>.5:
        return hdi
    else:
        return 0
mydataframe['ADJ_HDI'] = mydataframe.apply(lambda row: adj_hdi(row), axis = 1)
```

Comment: generates a warning but when i display the dataframe it is working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution:

```
homework2['ADJ_HDI'] = 0
homework2.loc[(homework2['HDI'] > 0.5), ['ADJ_HDI']] = homework2['HDI']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use very fast solution with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
homework2['ADJ_HDI'] = np.where(homework2['HDI'] > .5, homework2['HDI'], 0)
```

**Timings**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

homework2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 8, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                           "HDI": [25, np.nan, 2.3, 2.4, 1.2, 0.3, 5.7]})

#for test 7k uncomment row bellow  
#homework2 =  pd.concat([homework2]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
print homework2
h = homework2.copy()
h1 = homework2.copy()
```

```
def a(mydataframe):
    def adj_hdi(row):
        hdi = row['HDI']
        if hdi>.5:
            return hdi
        else:
            return 0
    mydataframe['ADJ_HDI'] = mydataframe.apply(lambda row: adj_hdi(row), axis = 1)
    return mydataframe

def b(homework2):
    homework2['ADJ_HDI'] = 0
    homework2.loc[(homework2['HDI'] > 0.5), ['ADJ_HDI']] = homework2['HDI']
    return homework2

def c(homework2):
    homework2['ADJ_HDI'] = np.where(homework2['HDI'] > .5, homework2['HDI'], 0)
    return homework2 

print a(homework2)    
print b(h)  
print c(h1)
```

`len(homework2) = 7`:

```
In [2]: %timeit a(homework2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 376 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit b(h)
The slowest run took 4.62 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit c(h1)
The slowest run took 5.52 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 283 µs per loop
```

`len(homework2) = 7k`:

```
In [7]: %timeit a(homework2)
10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit b(h)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.63 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit c(h1)
The slowest run took 5.30 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 324 µs per loop
```